# How to create a group | sub-group (pre-defined) cyclic order by considering the identical consecutive groupings (in Pandas DataFrame) columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, python-itertools, dictionary-comprehension

**Task 1:** I am looking for a solution to create a group by considering the identical consecutive groupings in one of the columns (of my Panda's DataFrame, ..considering this as values of a list):

```
from itertools import groupby

test_list = ['AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'DD', 'DD', 'AA', 'BB', 'EE', 'CC']
data = pd.DataFrame(test_list)
data['batches'] = ['1','1','2','3','4','4','4','5','6','7','8'] # this is the goal to reach
print(data)

result = [list(y) for x, y in groupby(test_list)]
print(result)

[['AA', 'AA'], ['BB'], ['CC'], ['DD', 'DD', 'DD'], ['AA'], ['BB'], ['EE'], ['CC']]
```

So, I have a DataFrame with two columns: the first is a list of elements that must be kept in order + grouped into batches: **identical consecutive grouping**. The batch column where the result should be assigned.

I couldn't find a solution or a workaround. As you can see, I've created a list using the itertools groupby function by grouping the same cons. items, but this isn't the final result I'd like to see. **I know that itertools groupby allows me to utilize a lambda function with the 'key=' parameter to perhaps get to my solution**.

I was thinking of merging the above and **looping it into a dictionary, with the key being the batch numbers obtained by iterating the list using enumerate and the values being the list elements**:

`{1:['AA', 'AA'], 2:['BB'], 3:['CC'], 4: ['DD', 'DD', 'DD']...}`

After that, I'll convert the dictionary (or any other solution/workaround) to a Data Series and add it to my batch column:

**In this exercise, I just want to return the key(s) of my 'dictionary' (the number of unique batches) to the batches column.**

```
| list     | batches |
| -------- | ------- |
| AA       | 1       |
| AA       | 1       |
| BB       | 2       |
| CC       | 3       |
| DD       | 4       |
| DD       | 4       |
| DD       | 4       |
| AA       | 5       |
| BB       | 6       |
| EE       | 7       |
| CC       | 8       |
```

---

**EDITED:**

**Task 2**: The added query for a similar task:

In this scenario, **my initial list has a (pre-defined) cyclic order** to follow such as AA -- AB -- AC belongs to one main group, DA -- DB -- belongs to another group.

The question is how to calculate the column sub-group so that I can have sub-groups listings under my main group...so to say, capturing repeated groups within the main group.

| list | sub | main gr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 1 | 1 |
| AB | 1 | 1 |
| AC | 1 | 1 |
| AA | 2 | 1 |
| AB | 2 | 1 |
| AC | 2 | 1 |
| DA | 1 | 2 |
| DB | 1 | 2 |

I found a solution whose logic was based on @Shubham's comment. My solution to use the `.cumcount()` function as the following: `df['sub'] = df.groupby(['main gr', 'list'].cumcount()+1`  `.cumcount()+1` if we want that the sub-order count/index starts at 1 instead 0.

(I'm not looking for the best solution, I am looking for a solution. Nevertheless, I would like to use this code for large datasets containing millions of entries).

**I will highly appreciate any comment or supporting feedback.**

Comment: Check with `cumsum` `data['batches'] = (data[0] != data[0].shift()).cumsum()`

Comment: Thank you very very much!! Could you please advise on the simplest way to add any string element to the newly constructed 'batches' column? As an example, before (the result of the cumsum of the.shift bool result), add the **"batch"** string, resulting:  batch 1, batch 1, batch 2, batch 3...

Comment: Glad i could help! To add the string element we can use `data['batches'] = (data[0] != data[0].shift()).cumsum().astype(str).radd('batch ')`

Comment: Thanks again @ShubhamSharma, nailed it! If I may inquire as to the distinction between.radd() and the plain + operation:   The result of your suggestion is what I expected, however the + operator appends the added string element ('batch') to the end. I assumed.radd() and + sign did the same thing, so why do they behave differently?

Comment: Lets say you have a series `s` containing `strings` and suppose you want to concat some other string lets say `x` to the series `s`, using `s + x` is equivalent to `s.add(x)` while `s.radd(x)` is equivalent to using `x + s`

Comment: could you please check my edit at the end of my main entry question? I think you might know how to solve my query

Comment: I think I figured it out a way, using the `.cumcount()` function: `df['sub'] = df.groupby(['main gr', 'list'].cumcount()+1`  `.cumcount()+1` if we want that the sub-order count/index starts at 1 instead 0.